# jQuery prepend method not working on input

Tags: jquery

I'd like to add some text to each `<input>` element of a form. For this I tried to use jQuery's *prepend* method. But it doesn't seem to work. 
In the following example it works for the form- and p-Elements, but not the input-Elements. What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("form,input,p").each(function(){
                    $(this).prepend("<p>Hello "+$(this).attr("id")+"</p>");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="p1">Some text</p>
        <form id="frm">
            <input type="text" id="foo" />
            <input type="text" id="bar" />
            <p id="p2">Some more text</p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should consider using `label` elements for the `input`s.

Comment: @undefined: That's exactly what I'm going to do. I used the <p>-Element only for demonstration purposes :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually seeing the normal behaviour. You cannot prepend anything inside of the `input` tag. Because, basically `input` is a `void element`. It does not contain any `contents/elements` inside it.

Please read here : [void elements](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/syntax.html#void-element)

Comment: Thanks! It appears I confused "prepend" with "before". Sometimes it helps to actually read the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because inputs are self-closed (void) entities in html. The can not contain TEXT-entities, like forms and parargraphs.
Instead they use "value" attribute.

Try this:

```
$("input").each(function(){
    $(this).val("Hello "+$(this).attr("id")+$(this).val());
});
```